# How to connect via R to MS SQL database requiring integrated active directory authentication using odbc and DBI packages?

Tags: r, odbc, r-dbi

I am currently trying to connect to some SQL databases from within RStudio.

The first database that uses windows authentication I can access easily using:

```
con <- dbConnect(odbc(), Driver = "SQL Server", Server = "ServerName", 
                 Database = "DatabaseName", Trusted_Connection = "True")
```

However we have another database that requires integrated active directory authentication and the above code (changed for the relevant server and database names) generates the error:

```
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:950: HY000: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Windows logins are not supported in this version of SQL Server.
```

I have tried various things including the following:

```
con <- dbConnect(odbc(), Driver = "SQL Server", Server = "Server_Two_Name", 
                 Database = "Database_2_Name", Trusted_Connection = "True", Authentication = "ActiveDirectoryIntegrated")

con <- dbConnect(odbc(), Driver = "SQL Server", Server = "Server_Two_Name", 
                 Database = "Database_2_Name", Trusted_Connection = "FALSE", Authentication = "ActiveDirectoryIntegrated")
```

However nothing I have tried allows me to connect successfully. (I can successfully connect to the database using SQL Server Management Studio if I specify the server and database names and set the authentication to "Active Directory - Integrated", without needing to enter a password or user name).

I have tried reading the guidance at https://db.rstudio.com and the documentation for the DBI and odbc packages but I did not fully understand the information provided.

Please can anyone advise?

Comment: Isn't the error clear enough: *Windows logins are not supported in this version of SQL Server*? What version are you using? SQL Server Express?

Comment: What is your client operating system? On https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/using-azure-active-directory?view=sql-server-2017 I have found: "The ODBC Driver on Linux and macOS does not support Active Directory Federation Services. If you are using Azure Active Directory username/password authentication from a Linux or macOS client and your Active Directory configuration includes Federated Services, authentication may fail."

Comment: Did you try using the `.connection_string` option of odbc::dbConnect? That worked for me.

Comment: Try `Authentication = "ActiveDirectoryInteractive"`.

Answer (score 1):

This works for my Azure cloud SQL Server databases that require "Azure Active Directory - Integrated" authentication:

```
#Database Connection Details
SQL_SERVER_NAME <- "Your SQL Server Name Goes Here"
SQL_DATABASE_NAME <- "Your Database Name Goes Here"

# Connect to database (assumes odbc and DBI packages are installed and libraries added)
con <- dbConnect(odbc(),
  Driver = "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
  Server = SQL_SERVER_NAME,
  Database = SQL_DATABASE_NAME,
  Authentication = "ActiveDirectoryIntegrated"
)
```

Note too that this also requires the [ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56567) to be installed on your machine.